# Calcular la media de 20 valores iguales de forma sencilla

Tags: shell-script

Quiero sacar el promedio de una variable que pido por teclado y que guarda 20 valores. Necesito sacar el promedio total entre todos, es decir, como si sumase 20 veces el mismo campo y luego lo dividiera por 20.

¿Hay alguna forma de hacer esto, que sea lo más simple posible, he pensado en tal vez poner alguna variable de suma y sumar la variable, pero no sé la forma de poder hacerlo?

La línea a arreglar sería la de:

```
MEDIA=`expr  \( $VALOR + $VALOR + VALOR + VALOR +  VALOR + $VALOR + $VALOR + VALOR + VALOR + VALOR + $VALOR + $VALOR + VALOR + VALOR + VALOR + $VALOR + $VALOR + VALOR + VALOR + VALOR \)  \/ 20
```

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
#!/bin/bash
VALOR=0
MAYOR=0
MENOR=999
CONTADOR=1

while [ $CONTADOR -le 20 ]
      do
            echo “Introduce un valor”
            read VALOR
                  if [ $VALOR -gt $MAYOR ]
                        then
                              MAYOR=$VALOR
                  fi
                        if [ $VALOR -le $MENOR ]
                              then
                                    MENOR=$VALOR
                       fi
                            MEDIA=`expr  \( $VALOR + $VALOR + VALOR + VALOR +  VALOR + $VALOR + $VALOR + VALOR + VALOR + VALOR + $VALOR + $VALOR + VALOR + VALOR + VALOR + $VALOR + $VALOR + VALOR + VALOR + VALOR \)  \/ 20
                             CONTADOR=$(($CONTADOR+1)
      done
echo “El mayor es $MAYOR”
echo “El menor es $MENOR”
echo “La media es $MEDIA”
```

Comment: @fedorqui, ya le puede valer porque esa pregunta también es suya :D

Comment: @ordago sí, lo sé :) no entiendo por qué pregunta de nuevo

Comment: Os lo explico, no entiendo nada del código, son proyectos para clase, y no me puedo salir más allá de while, ni for, por eso lo vuelvo a preguntar, para sacarlo pero con un código mucho más simple.

Comment: entonces deberías hacer preguntas más concretas. En lugar de preguntar cómo hacer un ejercicio, pregunta cómo hacer un bucle o cosas así